# Запрос sql с присвоением столбцу auto-increment?

Tags: mysql, sql

В таблице `wp_options` имеется столбец `option_id`. Как правильно составить sql запрос, чтобы:

1. `option_id` модифицировать до auto-increment + выставился флаг 'первичный ключ'.
2. Все значения этого столбца стали уникальными. В настоящий момент они равны нулям, а нужно что бы они выстроились друг за другом примерно в варианте 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 и т.п. ...

Comment: А если пересоздать столбец с флагом auto-increment и первичный ключ? Всё равно же данных нет

Comment: Не разрешает, пишет что в столбе имеются одинаковые элементы, типа вначале их измените, а потом и auto-increment вешайте

Comment: Ну так `ALTER TABLE wp_options DROP COLUMN option_id`. А потом заново вставляйте уже с флагами

Comment: Пишите заявку, я выберу как ответ.. Спасибо! =)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вначале вам нужно перенумеровать записи.

```
SET @id = 0;
UPDATE wp_options SET
  option_id = (SELECT @id := @id + 1);
```

Ну а потом навесить ограничение первичного ключа и добавить автоинкремент

```
ALTER TABLE wp_options MODIFY COLUMN
  option_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```